# Splunk change chart color

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have this graph:

[image]

How can I change the color for every column from x-axis?
For example, green for Low, yellow for Medium, orange for High and red for Critical

A part from query:

| eval status=case(duration>=0 AND duration<0.2, "Low", duration>=0.2 AND duration<0.5, "Medium", duration>=0.5 AND duration<0.7, "High", duration>=0.7, "Critical")

| chart count as "Requests" by status

| eval customSort=case(status="Low", 1, status="Medium", 2, status="High", 3, status="Critical", 4)

| sort customSort

| fields - customSort

Comment: unrelated to your question - but your search will likely run faster if you set your "status" field to the numeric values used for "customSort", and then change it from a number to text after it's sorted

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a Classic Dashboard. If you want each `status` to have a different colour, then each `status` must represent a different `series` in your data.

###### Your Current Results:

| status | Requests |
| --- | --- |
| Low | 10 |
| Medium | 20 |
| High | 30 |
| Critical | 40 |

###### Must be converted to:

| Low | Medium | High | Critical |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |

To achieve this please append this SPL to your search:

```
| transpose column_name=status header_field=status
```

You can then go into your XML Source and add the following tag to your chart (feel free to change this slapdash colour-scheme).

```xml
<option name="charting.fieldColors">{"Critical":#FF0000,"High":#FF7600,"Medium":#FFE500,"Low":#007840}</option>
```